# Warning in C# (xamarin.forms) using visual studio 2017

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

when i just create a xamarin.forms project the visual studio show me this warning and when i try to lunch the project it is stop after while and tell me there were deployment errors .what i must to do

> Warning   IDE0006 Error encountered while loading the project. Some project features, such as full solution analysis for the failed project and projects that depend on it, have been disabled.

Comment: Usually it creates new forms project targetting iOS. If you do not have configured mac connection or missing some iOS components it would fail. Same could be try for any of the platforms i.e missing all components needed for Android development or not having proper Windows 10 Sdk to develop UWP apps that you set as the target platform. Try to change startup project to another project and try again.

Comment: thanks for help but i tried to change startup project to another project but it dose not work

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like an error in the code analysis module which is used for code rules. It is not currently supported for several new project types such as .NET Standard 2.0. You will not be able to find the option to turn it off inside Visual Studio. You will need to edit the project file. Try opening it up in notepad, it might look something like this:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <RunCodeAnalysis>true</RunCodeAnalysis>
    <CodeAnalysisRuleSet>CodeRules.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
  </PropertyGroup>
```